# Foreign key with duplicates and no primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table A with below structure

```
Contract_ID     Parent_Contarct_ID      Client_ID
--------------------------------------------------
CON_001         CON_001                 CLNT_20001
CON_002         CON_002                 CLNT_20002
CON_003         CON_003                 CLNT_20003
CON_004         CON_004                 CLNT_20004
```

Here the Contract_ID has duplicates and so I am unable to create the Primary key or unique key.

But I need to reference this contract_ID in some other tables. How to refer if I am not creating a foreign key?

I am using mysql

Comment: Either delete the duplicates or create another unique column and make _that_ a primary key.

Comment: Without primary u cant ref it to some other table. That will violate all rules of RDMS. Ull need to some kinda Unique values.

Comment: To refer it in some other tables, it needs to be a primary key in this table. so you have to delete the duplicates or just create one more field as a primary key.

Comment: Possibly just add an identity column and set that as a primary key, which is refferenced in other tables.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing a fundemental understanding of your data.  What does it mean to have duplicates?  If you truly think the contract IDs should be unique and it is not then you have a data problem (and a bug in whatever software put that data there).  If duplicates are ok then what does that mean?

Sure you can add an identity and link to that but that does nothing to fix your actual problem - you will just end up back here asking why you get too many rows back for a given contract!

So number one step is to understand your data.  Then clean it if necessary.  Only then can you put all your PK & FK constraints in the correct place with what ever columns make sense.